# Square-Connect Item or Variation id(s) already exist

Tags: square-connect

I was messing around with the Square Connect API, and after uploading some items and finding out they had incorrect pricing (I was sending the amount in dollars, not cents) I decided to delete all of the items and start over. I am passing in item ids so that I can cross reference the items with our in-house database. Unfortunately, it appears that after I've deleted an item, I can't recreate it with the same old id. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, item and variation IDs can never be reused for a given merchant. I will update the documentation to better clarify this limitation.

As a couple of potential solutions for your issue:

- You could recreate your item library with item IDs that all have the same prefix, followed by the corresponding ID in your in-house database. Then prepend or remove the prefix when translating between IDs in your two systems. Of course, this solution is still susceptible to the same root issue, so you'd have to make sure not to delete any items.
- Store the ID mapping in the `user_data` field of your item variations. You can set the `user_data` field with the [Update Variation](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api#put-variationid) endpoint.